# Applications list disappear from task manager when launch MFC applcation

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, taskmanager

I write MFC application, but when i launch it, in task manager on applications tab all applications list are disapear. if i do active some applications then she appears in applicion list, and when i close my MFC app all aplications are appears in app list on application tab. Why this happening?

Comment: Did you had test your application in another machine? I think there is something wrong in your Windows.

Comment: maybe but when i create default mfc application, this bug with task manager not happend. so that means that i do something wrong and this a reason this bug.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are using Vista or Win 7, you are running your application as Administrator and task manager is NOT set to show all tasks from all users.

Comment: @lebron: Oh well ... ruined that thought! ;)